# Fetch data from PySpark and transfrom it and save data into databases

Tags: pandas, pyspark, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

I am new to Python and spark.

We are using Azure Databrick and with help of PySpark code shown below for it.

```
data=spark.sql("SELECT  'Name' as name, 'Number' as number FROM Student")

print(data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will work for you.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
data2 = [("Finance",10),
    ("Marketing",20),
    ("Sales",30),
    ("IT",40)
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("Name",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("number", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)

df1 = df.withColumn("Student",lit("Student")).select("Student",to_json(struct("Name","number")).alias("Data"))
display(df1)
```

[image]

Comment: you are a example of  real life angle :)